# ggplot, trying to change the order of my x value labels, scale_fill_discrete not working

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a dataframe and the `x` values are "first", "second" ... so on.

The ggplot function plotted them alphabetically instead of numerically.

I tried to use

```
scale_fill_discrete(
  breaks = c("First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth")
)
```

The barplot is still coming out with the wrong order
here is the full code

```
gender_1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = `Call Attempt`, y = `Count`, fill = `Gender`)) +
  geom_col(position dodge) + 
  scale_fill_discrete(
    breaks = c("First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth")
  )
```

I used

```
scale_fill_discrete(
  breaks = c("First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth")
)
```

and the order came out alphabetically instead of numerically

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: This said: As you want to order "the x values" try with `scale_x_discrete` instead of `scale_fill_discrete` and use the `limits` instead of the `breaks`, i.e. do `scale_x_discrete(limits = c("First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth"))`.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(gender_1)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(gender_1, 20))`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use an (ordered) factor for your gender variable:

```
library(ggplot2)
# Example data

Gender<-c("First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth")
frame<-data.frame(X=1:6,Y=rnorm(6),Gender)

# ggplot orders this alphabetically (not what you want)
ggplot(frame,aes(X,Y,fill=Gender))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")

# by using a factor and explicitly specifiying 
# its levels (and the order of the levels) you force ggplot to abandon alphabetical order

ggplot(frame,aes(X,Y,fill=factor(Gender,levels = Gender)))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```